# Need Suggestions for Responsive Design Issue - Works on Desktop but Not on Mobile

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm encountering an issue with the responsiveness of my design that I hope you can help me with. Currently, the design appears to be functioning correctly on desktop browsers, but when viewed on mobile devices, it's not rendering as expected.

I've implemented a responsive design using media queries and other techniques to ensure adaptability across various screen sizes. However, despite these efforts, the layout doesn't adjust properly on mobile devices.

**Repository:**
[*Repo*](https://github.com/natancent/rating_component.git)

**Live webpage**
[*Live*](https://rating-component-th5w.vercel.app/)

I've used media queries to target different screen sizes and orientations.
The layout uses percentage-based widths and max-width properties to allow flexibility.
I've also checked for any fixed widths or hardcoded values that might be causing the issue.
Despite these precautions, the design still fails to display correctly on mobile screens. I've tested it on multiple devices and browsers to confirm the issue persists across different environments.

I'd greatly appreciate any suggestions or insights on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue. If you need specific code snippets or further details about my implementation, please let me know, and I'll provide them promptly.

Comment: One thing I found is, setting the `input` to `margin: 0 auto;display: block;`. 

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: "I've also checked for any fixed widths or hardcoded values that might be causing the issue." Nearly everything in the layout uses fixed widths and heights.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fixed in this repo, https://github.com/sdz28r/rating_component/tree/master

For comparison you can see the PR
https://github.com/natancent/rating_component/pull/1/files

**Always keep in mind not to centre things using hardcoded paddings / margins. One of the main issues in your code is related to that only, also try giving classes to individual elements instead of applying the css directly to tags.**

Comment: Please don't fix things "out of band" like this. It's nice of you to do for the user, of course, and you can of course do that on your own time, but if you're going to make an answer on SO about it, you need to share exactly what was done and why. This question was entirely too broad and opinion-based, in addition to not providing the code as a [mre] here on Stack Overflow, that it should not be answered, only closed.